apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.multipass"
I am trying to use multipass to create machines and provision them. However, I am being blocked by apparmor:
journalctl -n 100 | grep multipass                                                                                                01:45:51
Sep 29 01:45:51 davidshare systemd[4003]: Started snap.multipass.multipass-3052ccb3-3488-40e0-b1db-ec0c7faadef5.scope.
Sep 29 01:45:51 davidshare kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1727570751.680:943): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.multipass" name="/proc/23809/maps" pid=23809 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Sep 29 01:45:51 davidshare kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1727570751.699:944): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.multipass.multipass" name=2F6D656469612F646176696473686172652F54657273752F5465727375436F72702F746572737520746563682F6C6561726E696E67204465764F70732F4B756265726E657465732D7461736B732F6D756C7469706173732D6B38732D636C75737465722F636F6E6669672F64656269616E2D636C6F75642D696E69742E79616D6C pid=23789 comm="multipass" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Sep 29 01:45:51 davidshare systemd[4003]: Started snap.multipass.multipass-b76571ab-0f9a-499c-9d09-064c2a470fb4.scope.
Sep 29 01:45:51 davidshare kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1727570751.725:945): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.multipass" name="/proc/23853/maps" pid=23853 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Sep 29 01:45:51 davidshare kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1727570751.744:946): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.multipass.multipass" name=2F6D656469612F646176696473686172652F54657273752F5465727375436F72702F746572737520746563682F6C6561726E696E67204465764F70732F4B756265726E657465732D7461736B732F6D756C7469706173732D6B38732D636C75737465722F636F6E6669672F64656269616E2D636C6F75642D696E69742E79616D6C pid=23835 comm="multipass" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Sep 29 01:45:51 davidshare systemd[4003]: Started snap.multipass.multipass-c350cf43-aca2-4576-bdb0-521748d79ea7.scope.
Sep 29 01:45:51 davidshare kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1727570751.776:947): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.multipass" name="/proc/23896/maps" pid=23896 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Sep 29 01:45:51 davidshare kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1727570751.794:948): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.multipass.multipass" name=2F6D656469612F646176696473686172652F54657273752F5465727375436F72702F746572737520746563682F6C6561726E696E67204465764F70732F4B756265726E657465732D7461736B732F6D756C7469706173732D6B38732D636C75737465722F636F6E6669672F64656269616E2D636C6F75642D696E69742E79616D6C pid=23879 comm="multipass" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Sep 29 01:45:51 davidshare systemd[4003]: Started snap.multipass.multipass-a1830d33-3795-4553-8c38-03a487fec7c5.scope.
Sep 29 01:45:51 davidshare kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1727570751.825:949): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.multipass" name="/proc/23937/maps" pid=23937 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Sep 29 01:45:51 davidshare kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1727570751.844:950): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.multipass.multipass" name=2F6D656469612F646176696473686172652F54657273752F5465727375436F72702F746572737520746563682F6C6561726E696E67204465764F70732F4B756265726E657465732D7461736B732F6D756C7469706173732D6B38732D636C75737465722F636F6E6669672F64656269616E2D636C6F75642D696E69742E79616D6C pid=23922 comm="multipass" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000

snap connections multipass                                                                                                        01:55:34
Interface               Plug                         Slot                            Notes
content[gnome-42-2204]  multipass:gnome-42-2204      gnome-42-2204:gnome-42-2204     -
content[gtk-3-themes]   multipass:gtk-3-themes       gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes  -
content[icon-themes]    multipass:icon-themes        gtk-common-themes:icon-themes   -
content[sound-themes]   multipass:sound-themes       gtk-common-themes:sound-themes  -
desktop                 multipass:desktop            :desktop                        -
desktop-legacy          multipass:desktop-legacy     :desktop-legacy                 -
firewall-control        multipass:firewall-control   :firewall-control               -
gsettings               multipass:gsettings          :gsettings                      -
home                    multipass:all-home           :home                           -
kvm                     multipass:kvm                :kvm                            -
libvirt                 multipass:libvirt            :libvirt                        manual
lxd                     multipass:lxd                lxd:lxd                         -
multipass-support       multipass:multipass-support  :multipass-support              -
network                 multipass:network            :network                        -
network-bind            multipass:network-bind       :network-bind                   -
network-control         multipass:network-control    :network-control                -
network-manager         multipass:network-manager    :network-manager                -
network-observe         multipass:network-observe    :network-observe                -
opengl                  multipass:opengl             :opengl                         -
removable-media         multipass:removable-media    :removable-media                manual
system-observe          multipass:system-observe     :system-observe                 -
unity7                  multipass:unity7             :unity7                         -
wayland                 multipass:wayland            :wayland                        -
x11                     multipass:x11                :x11                            -


Please how do I solve this without changing the directory of my files. Or by giving multipass the permissions it needs?
tree                                                                                                                              02:00:31
.
├── config
│   └── debian-cloud-init.yaml
├── create-vms.sh
├── managed_context
│   └── metadata.json
├── multipass-profile.log
└── test_suite_analysis
    └── metadata.json

the script that tries to run multipass
#!/bin/bash

# Launch VMs with multipass
multipass launch --name jumpbox --cpus 1 --memory 512M --disk 5G --cloud-init "$(pwd)/config/debian-cloud-init.yaml" --verbose
multipass launch --name master --cpus 1 --memory 2G --disk 10G --cloud-init "$(pwd)/config/debian-cloud-init.yaml" --verbose
multipass launch --name worker1 --cpus 1 --memory 2G --disk 10G --cloud-init "$(pwd)/config/debian-cloud-init.yaml" --verbose
multipass launch --name workder2 --cpus 1 --memory 2G --disk 10G --cloud-init "$(pwd)/config/debian-cloud-init.yaml" --verbose

The content of the config file:
#cloud-config
package_update: true
packages:
  - debootstrap
users:
  - name: root
    lock_passwd: false
    passwd: tersu
ssh_pwauth: true
disable_root: false
runcmd:
  - debootstrap --arch=arm64 bookworm /mnt http://deb.debian.org/debian/
  - mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
  - mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
  - mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
  - |
    chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y linux-image-arm64 systemd-sysv"
  - chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "apt-get install -y grub-efi"
  - |
    chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "grub-install --target=arm64-efi \
    --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-debian --recheck"
  - chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "update-grub"
  - |
    chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ \
    bookworm main' > /etc/apt/sources.list"
  - chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "echo 'root:password' | chpasswd"
  - |
    chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "sed -i 's/^#PermitRootLogin.*/\
    PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
  - chroot /mnt /bin/bash -c "systemctl enable ssh"
  - umount /mnt/dev
  - umount /mnt/proc
  - umount /mnt/sys
  - echo "Debian installation completed!"

